# What's (really) the use of the <a> tag?

Tags: html, theory

I know we use the `<a>` to make a hyperlink.

But what I don't know, why do we use the `<a>`, why isn't it possible to just add a `href` to a `<div>`, so this becomes a hyperlink?

Of course, I can do it with javascript, but i'm curious about the theory and maybe some interesting arguments behind this.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Why not add a `src` on a `div` instead of an `img`? Because it is 'by design'.

Comment: The most important attribute of the <a> element is the href attribute, which indicates the link's destination.

Comment: anchors are not only for hyperlinks. also you may navigate to anchors within a page. we use them because they are very usefl. If you want to anchor a div you may wrap it into an `<a>` tag also.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Some more reading for you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor

Comment: @Prisoner, if you can't answer constructive, please don't answer at all. We can't just accept everything just because 'it is the way it is', when you do, you will never advance.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I know it's by design. But can you tell me why?

Comment: I am the wrong person to ask that. Ask [Tim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee).

Comment: "Theory and interesting arguments" are not really the intended function of this site... it's more to ask specific questions that can be answered with fact and reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a pretty tough question to answer. Maybe the best approach to a somewhat reasonable answer would be to focus on why it should *not* be possible as described than why it might be possible.

First of all, we are talking about HTML, the HyperText markup language. Let's think of it as a description language of a resource. And having its history in mind, let's also assume that, in terms of resources, we are talking about simple text documents.

So now there are very basic concepts to describe such a document semantically, like "this is a heading" (h1), "this is a paragraph" (p), "this is a listing" (li) and so on.

One of those concepts is a link which is used to reference another resource. There are several types of links, e. g. for referencing a stylesheet (link), an image (img), or another document (form).

The a-element is semantically (!) bound to this concept and represents / describes the relationship between two resources. So you throw an anchor from the source to the destination and maybe describe this relationship. It's like drawing a line between 2 entities in a UML diagram and describing how they are related.

So, the `<p>` and the `<a>` elements describe totally different concepts. The one declares a paragraph in a text, the other one describes a relationship between resources.

So, from a semantic point of view, what would something like `<p href="other-page.html">Some Text</p>` mean? That a paragraph in a text is linked to another resource...? That the paragraph describes a relationship between resources? Does that even make sense? In a real book that would be something like a paragraph on page 1 saying "hey, I'm related to page 123". But then it would not be a paragraph anymore but a description of a relationship - and we already have this concept implemented by the `<a>` tag.

It's basically like saying

```
<p> 
   <a href="other-page.html">
        I'll just put the whole relationship description in a paragraph.
   </a>
</p>
```

What's the point? A paragraph is a paragraph and a link description is a link description. A paragraph may contain a link, but not only consist of a link, because that would not make much sense from a semantic perspective.

But let's go back to the future now. Nowadays we're dealing with way more complex documents and are focusing much more on the UI and how to make it look pretty instead of semantics. As long as it looks good, we (mostly) don't care if a text is wrapped in a `p`, a `div`, a `article` or a `span` element - after all, it's just a description and in most cases we just need something to reference from the CSS or JS.

So humans don't care about the markup, but computers do. The same semantics are still true and they are the only way for computers like the Google bot to figure out what part of the document they're dealing with and how to handle it (like: "hey, this is an article, this is probably the most important part" or "that's just the footer, don't mind the duplicate content").

In the early days there was no way to "style" the elements, so it probably looked a little different in different user agents. The user agent just knew: "ok, this is a heading, let's make that bold and increase the font-size a little".

So each element has it's own purpose and separated concerns. And when you try to merge them, not only you would have to combine the properties of both (duplicate attributes, different handling in browsers, ...) but you also would have to describe what it means. And you probably would find out that it doesn't make any sense.

I hope at least this answer did make any sense and that it answers your question in some way.

Comment: this does clarify a lot more than the useless previous comments. thanks a lot:)